# asp.net gridview stop header and footer from changing color on mouseover

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, mouseover

I am using the following jquery script to highlight each row on an asp.net gridview and works fine.
However the header and footer of the grid also change color on mouseover, which obviously I don't want it to happen.

Any ideas what else I need to insert on the script to stop grid header/footer from changing colors ?

thanks

```
 $("table.STD_GridView tr").mouseover(function (event) {                        
                        var color = $(this).css("background-color");
                        $(this).css("background", "#f6f6f6");
                        $(this).bind("mouseout", function () {
                            $(this).css("background", color);
                        })
                    }
```

AMMENDMENT:

Here is some of the code (header related) created:

```
<th align="left" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$VF&#39;)" style="color:White;">Validity</a></th>
```

Comment: Does the gridview generate `tbody` tags? You can narrow down your selector to `table.STD_GridView tbody tr`

Comment: thanks but it doesn't seem to generate tbody tags. I've tried using $("table.STD_GridView tbody tr").mouseover(function (event) { and didn't do anything (still changing header/footer background color)

Comment: Can you post some of the generated markup of the gridview?

Comment: the gridview markup is quite long as there are many columns, etc...however I have added to the post one of the header column titles...I am not sure if that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gridviews allow you to style the header and footer separate from the datarows, which themselves can be styled.  and by styleing I mean ass a class name.  for example:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="gvHeaderStyle" ></tr>
  <tr class="gvRowStyle" ></tr>
  <tr class="gvAlternatingRowStyle"></tr>
  <tr class="gvFooterStyle"></tr>
</tbody>
```

it should be a simple matter to do something like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="gvHeaderStyle" ></tr>
  <tr class="gvRowStyle HoverableRow" ></tr>
  <tr class="gvAlternatingRowStyle HoverableRow"></tr>
  <tr class="gvFooterStyle"></tr>
</tbody>
```

and then just jquery for this:

```
$("table.STD_GridView tr.HoverableRow").mouseover( ...
```

But at this point you could forgo the jquery and just do a css thing:

```
.HoverableRow {
  background-color: <default>;
}
.HoverableRow:hover {
  background-color: #F6F6F6
}
```

Comment: fantastic! that does it!

Comment: css works just as good ! Will get rid of jquery script then. I am not sure why I used jquery instead of css...I guess it was the first code I found when searched for it on the internet. I appreciate your guidance.